# Django: export view with variables as a plain text download

Tags: python, django

I am very new to Django.

I have a working template that passes a variable/object (configs) and allows me reference objects such as:

```
{{ config.id }}
{{ config.hostname }}
```

All is working well and the text shows up as plain text in the browser, but I would like to be able to export the data from this template to a plain text file that can be downloaded (that is not stored on the server, it would be generated by a form) and have the variables/objects that users enter passed to this template. Perhaps the file could be called something like output.txt and would prompt the user with the familiar 'open with/save as' dialog box.

example of `views.py`:

```
def configs_detail(request, pk):
  configs = get_object_or_404(Configurations, pk=pk)
  return render(request, 'configs/configs_detail.html', {'configs': configs})
```

example of `urls.py`

```
url(r'^configs/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/$', views.configs_detail, name='configs_detail'),
```

example of `configs_detail.html` template:

```
{{ configs.hostname }}
{{ configs.state }}
{{ configs.config }}
```

I have played around and gotten the download of plain text to work but cannot seem to get the plain text + variables + download link to all work together.

Thanks

edit: thanks to Daniel / xbello / danihp for their inputs

### Answer:

Finally got it to work with: (this is just a test project, now it's working it will be cleaned up and proper view names etc will be used)

`views.py`:

```
def special_view(request, pk):
  configs = get_object_or_404(Configurations, pk=pk)
  return render(request, 'configs/output.txt', {'configs': configs}, content_type='text/plain; charset=utf-8')

def special_view_three(request, pk):
  configs = get_object_or_404(Configurations, pk=pk)
  response = HttpResponse(content_type='text/plain; charset=utf-8')
  response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="output_three.txt"'

  t = loader.get_template('configs/output.txt')
  c = Context({
    'configs': configs,
  })

  response.write(t.render(c))
  return response
```

`urls.py`:

```
url(r'^special_view/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/$', views.special_view, name='special_view'),
url(r'^special_view_three/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/$', views.special_view_three, name='special_view_three'),
```

`configs/output.txt` template:

```
{{ configs.hostname }}
{{ configs.state }}
{{ configs.config }}
```

Comment: Why are you rendering an HTML template if you want to download a pure text file?

Comment: ah yes, silly me, included html...better now without that, thanks. The next part will be downloading the actual file that I see on the screen via a prompt of some sort

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [`render`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/http/shortcuts/#render) function accepts an [optional parameter](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/http/shortcuts/#optional-arguments) called `content_type`. If you set it as `text/plain` you should get what you want:

```
render(request, 'configs/output.txt', {'configs': configs},
       content_type="text/plain")
```

Comment: thanks for that, was looking through the documents and just stumbled across it to...almost there, just need to work out how to download the actual file that I see on the screen via a prompt of some sort. I think I might need to somehow put Content-Disposition of attachment in there...

Comment: @savager1 , answer is right. You are asking for a new question. To get desired new behavior you should to create another view with a link to this one.

Comment: @danihp ah thanks for that I can see what you mean, but sorry struggling to link the two views. I now have the view from above: `config_detail` and I have created another view: `special_view` (name not important), which has the Content-Disposition of attachment in it...but cannot see how to link them. Any chance of an example? - ah nevermind got it, updating first post, thanks. awesome! sorry pretty simple in hindsight